# Convert XOR to NOR

Tags: logic

For a course assignment, we were asked to look up how to convert between various logic gates by creating systems involving two inputs `A` and `B` and one output `O`. The last conversion was from `XOR` to `NOR`, but I can't seem to find any answers out there. The logic for each of these is as follows:

```
XOR
A | B | O
----------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 0

NOR
A | B | O
----------
0 | 0 | 1
1 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 1 | 0
```

For simplicity, I'll request pseudo-code for a function `NOR` rather than a diagram. The `XOR` binary operator is `^`. The closest I came was the following function in JavaScript:

```
function nor(a, b) {
    return ((a^1)^(a^b))^((b^0)^(a^b));
}
```

But this is actually the logic for `XNOR`:

```
A | B | O
----------
0 | 0 | 1
1 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 1 | 1 (this should be 0 though)
```

Anyone else who can figure this out?

**EDIT** To summarize, make a `NOR` operator / function of two arguments using `A`, `B`, the constants `0` and `1` as needed, and the only operator allowed is the `XOR` operator (`^`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing OR,AND using XOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197416/implementing-or-and-using-xor)

Comment: Ah you appear to be right... XOR is not a parity generator and not a universal gate, whereas NOR is a universal gate.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say XOR **is** a parity generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. For instance, you can check

```
a XOR b XOR 1
```

to achieve equivalence, but you cannot exclude `AND` from it, because `XOR` is not a universal gate.

Answer (score 0):

Not going to give complete solution to homework. But I was curious and so:

You write you have `A` `B` and `0` as inputs, but you use a `1` as input in your code.

If you are not allowed to to use `1`, you might want to consider what `A XOR 0` is.

Your edit looks like `1` is allowed, in which case as far as I can see the solution is to use the direct input in one side of a gate, and a combined input as the other. Like ((a) ^ (a ^ b)).

*EDIT* Posted the reply without a finished solution so you had something to work on. Just noting it is possible there is no solution.

Comment: Worked on it some, thought it about it while cooking. Can't make a solution, but also been unable to prove that one can't be made. What got me troubled with proving it is impossible is you can make (b ^ a) ^ b that is true if a is true.

Comment: the output is ``O``, there is no input other than ``A`` and ``B``. ``0`` is neither an input nor an output. It is true that there is no solution.