# Is there any way to represent the AND function in terms of only XOR's and NOT's?

Tags: function, logic

I have been attempting it for the last hour with truth tables and it has not got me anywhere, is it even possible??

Comment: I don' t think it's possible, since XOR is a parity function. All you can do with XOR gates is set the output to represent even or odd parity. See this [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197416/implementing-or-and-using-xor) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing OR,AND using XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197416/implementing-or-and-using-xor)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

Plot a tree of possible functions.

Step 1, you have as possible inputs A, B, 1 and 0.

Step 2, you may combine them into A xor B, A xor 1, B xor 1, A xor 0 and B xor 0.
You may observe that X xor 0 is simply X, and X xor 1 is (not x)

Step 3, combine all the pairs of functions you got on step 1 and 2. The only new function you'll get will be not (A xor B).

Step 4, no new functions at all, any combination will give one of the previous.

So, no way to get to A and B.

Comment: Thanks. Does this also apply to the OR function?

Comment: As I recall from my university days, only NAND and NOR are the universal blocks from which any logical function may be built.

Comment: If you have NOT and OR, you have NOR - which can be used to build anything.